# how to get the nearest html element to a target element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, element, document

How to get the nearest `<a>` tag to a target Element? At first, I was using `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)` but if the user clicked on a div containing the link then the href will be `null`, so I want to return the nearest link from the element and then get the href, how is this done? ***Without Jquery***

```
let cursorX = 0;
let cursorY = 0;

document.onmousemove = e => {
    cursorX = e.clientX;
    cursorY = e.clientY;
};

const getNearestImage = () => document.elementFromPoint(cursorX, cursorY)
```

This works fine, the problem comes with the link is nested in a div or something.

Comment: [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

Comment: Please create always(if possible) a snippet with tools `[<>]`

Comment: You have to be more clear. Is that based on the distance they are on screen or in the DOM tree?

Comment: I tried `Eleem.closes()` before but it's not working, I think it's because it gets the nearest parent element but not children's. Also I will include a snippet now

Comment: @TusharShahi I think it's DOM tree... I'm just trying to get the closest link to the cursor position (The user should put his cursor directly on a link, the problem comes when the link is inside a div)